# FETCH converted XHR request is not captured in CYPRESS RUN command

Tags: cypress

"npx run command" is not catching FETCH calls but same FETCH calls get captured in "npx cypress open" command and my cypress version is 3.4.1 and I use unfetch module in window:before:load cypress EVENT to capture FETCH converted XHR request, if any `enter code here`body faced this issue , please provide me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `unfetch`, I suspect it's due to that.  This is what I am using and it works with both `npx cypress open` and `npx cypress run` for us.  It comes from [this issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/687).

```
// In cypress/support/index.js

Cypress.on("window:before:load", win => {
  win.fetch = null;
});
```

Comment: Brendan , i think above code does not work in cypress 3.4.1 , could you please tell me what is the cypress version you are using ?

Comment: I've been using this successfully since way back on cypress 2.something, up until most recently with 3.7.0 and all versions in between.